# why this piece of code can get the function address from return address?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, stack, reverse-engineering

`return_address` is obtain by writing a small piece of assembly code getting the ebp and hence we can get the return address by increment the ebp by 4. 
Here `return_address` is of type `int` but we can cast it to `int*`

```
 int extract_function_address(int return_address) {
        int *offset_address_ptr = (int*)(return_address - 5 + 1);
        int offset = *offset_address_ptr;   
        int func_address = return_address + offset;

        return func_address;
    }
```

I use `gdb` to step through it

```
(gdb) disas bar
Dump of assembler code for function bar:
   0x08048304 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048305 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048307 <+3>: sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x0804830a <+6>: mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804830d <+9>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
   0x08048310 <+12>:    add    %edx,%eax
   0x08048312 <+14>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x08048315 <+17>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048318 <+20>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%ebp)
   0x0804831b <+23>:    mov    0x81e2460,%eax
   0x08048320 <+28>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048323 <+31>:    call   0x8048358 <traceback>
   0x08048328 <+36>:    leave  
   0x08048329 <+37>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.


(gdb) disas foo
Dump of assembler code for function foo:
   0x0804832a <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x0804832b <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x0804832d <+3>: sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x08048330 <+6>: movl   $0x11,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048338 <+14>:    movl   $0x5,(%esp)
   0x0804833f <+21>:    call   0x8048304 <bar>
   0x08048344 <+26>:    leave  
   0x08048345 <+27>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

I passed return address as `0x08048344` to the function. The offset will be `-64` and the return value will be `0x8048304` which is the starting address of bar.

Why is this work?

This is the C file where `bar` and `foo` locate

```
#include "traceback.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(int x, int y)
{
  int z;
  z = x + y;
  traceback(stdout);
}

void foo() {
  bar (5,17);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

I put that piece of code in `traceback(FILE *fp)`.

Comment: Sheer morbid curiosity, does it still work if you turn on full optimizations?

Comment: The flag I used in Makefile are `CFLAGS= -Wall -Werror -gstabs -O0 -m32 -Itraceback -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call instruction assembles to `E8 AA BB CC DD` where `AA BB CC DD` is the offset of the target function from the instruction following the call, i.e. from the return address. Try `x/5bx 0x0804833f` in gdb to see the encoded instruction. Note that the offset would be in little endian byte order.

Therefore, `(return_address - 5 + 1)` points to the offset of the call instruction. `offset = *offset_address_ptr` reads this offset from the call instruction and `return_address + offset` points to the target function.

Comment: Wow.. Thank you. I have completely no ideas about that. Do you know is there any reference, so that I can read more about it?

Comment: You can read some related stuff in articles on buffer overflows including the legendary article by Aleph One: [Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit](http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=49&id=14&mode=txt)

Comment: Yes. You are right. I checked out the intel architecture manual http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~410/doc/intel-isr.pdf on page 3-53. But is it always using a relative displacement? If it uses a direct address, the above code break?

Comment: Is it better to fetch the eip value?

Comment: Unless you are using pointer to functions (or something similar), the target address is known at compile time. The compiler will therefore generate code using 'near' calls with relative offsets as described on  page 3-53 of the manual.

Comment: Fetching the eip value will give you the address of an instruction inside the function, and not the address of the function. You can even use the name of the function to get its address, e.g. `printf("%x", bar);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it looks like the code fethes call-address from the instruction just before the return location.